# How can I concatenation parameter name out of 2 strings?

Tags: javascript

I have the following variable:

```
var MyVar = "8";
```

I have 2 strings for example:

```
var foo = "My";
var bar = "Var";
```

Now I want to alert MyVar value, meaning to alert "8" and not "MyVar"

```
alert(foo + bar) // returns "MyVar"
```

Comment: `alert(eval(foo + bar))`. But beware, this method is dangerous. For instance, imagine that either variable does not contain a part of a variable identifier, but evil code.

Comment: `eval` is only dangerous if the page is dynamic server side, and users have a way of interacting with the content (forums, comments, etc.) because then XSS is a concern. Users always can run whatever code they wish on a site, regardless of `eval` being present or not. The only time `eval` would be dangerous is when user's content is put into a function that calls `eval` within the function, so that other users would run the malicious script when the loaded the hackers post or comment or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing the context to much of what you are doing you can use the `eval` function. However, you have to be very careful with it.

```
var MyVar = 8;

var foo = "My";
var bar = "Var";

alert(eval(foo + bar));
```

Depending on what your doing though there are a lot of ways to do this. If you assign `MyVar` to be part of some context such as `this`, or `window` you can simply lookup the value with the key as the variable name.

Window Context

```
(function () {
  window.MyVar = 8;

  var foo = "My";
  var bar = "Var";

  alert(window[foo+bar]);
})();
```

Function Context

```
new (function () {
  this.MyVar = 8;

  var foo = "My";
  var bar = "Var";

  alert(this[foo+bar]);
})();
```

Object Context

```
(function () {
  var obj = {}
  obj.MyVar = 8;

  var foo = "My";
  var bar = "Var";

  alert(obj[foo+bar]);
})();
```

Comment: Your function context is actually global.

Comment: You'r right, care to elaborate as I'm not sure why. Do anonymous functions take on global context?

Comment: Inside a function, `this` will be the global object unless (a) the function is called as an object method (then `this` will be the object), or (b) the function is called as a constructor, with the `new` operator (in which case `this` will point to the new object being constructed). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 5):

This is a rare case where `eval` will be needed:

**Code**

```
var MyVar = "8",
    foo = "My",
    bar = "Var";
alert(eval(foo + bar))
```

**Link:** http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/wcVNU/

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's the only correct answer (matching the OPs question) on this page

Comment: +1.  I clearly misunderstood the question whereas you did not. :)

Comment: Okay, I removed the downvote. My point is, if you need "dynamic variables" and eval, you're probably doing it wrong. An object is the way to go in most cases.

Comment: +1. You can even eval in a variable : `var value = eval(foo + bar);`

Comment: @bfavaretto I agree, I can't see why the OP would need to do what he is doing, but `eval` is the way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming it's a global variable:

```
alert(window[foo + bar])
```

But you're probably better off using objects and properties for that. Object properties can also be accessed with bracket notation:

```
var obj = {
    MyProp : 8
};
var foo = "My";
var bar = "Prop";
alert(obj[foo + bar]);
```

Comment: Now, what if it's not a global variable?

Comment: What if it is a mix of global and non-global?

Comment: Hmmm, why am I getting undefined when I try this?